# React Native How to put button/image inside Circular Progress Bar (react-native-circular-progress-indicator)

Tags: react-native

Right now, I am using the CountdownCircleTimer as my "progress bar", but need one that counts up instead of down.

It looks like this, with a touchable image button in the middle that starts a recording.
[image]

```js
<CountdownCircleTimer
  isPlaying={progressCircle}
  size={74}
  strokeWidth={5}
  duration={60}
  colors={[["#000000", .001], [feedScreen ? "#F777B1" : "#64A6EC", .999]]}
  trailColor={"transparent"}
>
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={tw.style(`rounded-full overflow-hidden justify-center items-center`, {
          width: 62,
          height: 62,
          backgroundColor: "#000000",
      })}
      onPress={(e) => onPress(e)}
    >
        {children}
    </TouchableOpacity>
</CountdownCircleTimer>
```

I'm trying to implement the CircularProgress component, but it hides the image/button. The top is the old countdown timer in the picture above, the bottom is the new circular progress bar, hiding the image/button.

[image]

```js
<CircularProgress
  value={duration}
  delay={progressCircle}
  radius={37}
  activeStrokeWidth={5}
  activeStrokeColor={feedScreen ? "#F777B1" : "#64A6EC"}
  textColor={'transparent'}
>
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={tw.style(`rounded-full overflow-hidden justify-center items-center`, {
          width: 62,
          height: 62,
          backgroundColor: "#000000",
      })}
      onPress={(e) => onPress(e)}
    >
        {children}
    </TouchableOpacity>
</CircularProgress>
```

How can I put the image and button in the middle, like I did with the countdown circular?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use some form of absolute positioning.

Add something like this to your circular progress bar styling:

```js
position: 'absolute',
alignSelf: 'center',
bottom: 0
```

You can adjust the absolute positioning via the top, left, and right proeprties as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is that just how the component is? It does not allow for images inside?

Comment: Sorry, not actually sure. Can you link the component you used here?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-circular-progress-indicator

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing anywhere they support the center fill to be an image.